# XSLT: recursive templates on parametrized nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I am attempting to call a template recursively on a parametrized list of node types.

If I pass these parametrized values to a template, it doesn't recurse.
However, if I pass in the values to the template directly, the recursion works as expected.

How can I get the recursion to work while matching against a parametrized value?

(I am using saxon version 9.9.1.6 (home edition) to apply the XSLT transformation)

**Input HTML**

```
<p>
<p>paragraph1</p>
<p>paragraph2</p>
<a>link here</a>
</p>
```

**XSLT with direct value for template:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="container" select="p|a"/>    
<xsl:template match="p|a">
    Name: <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    Value: <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    Name: p
    Value: 

    Name: p
    Value: paragraph1

    Name: p
    Value: paragraph2

    Name: a
    Value: link here
```

This is working and what I would expect to happen.
But when I try and pass parametrized values to the template, it matches the top-level element but does not match any child elements.

**XSLT with parametrized value for template:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="container" select="p|a"/>    
<xsl:template match="$container">
    Name: <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    Value: <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    Name: p
    Value: 
paragraph1
paragraph2
link here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match="$variable"` is new syntax in XSLT 3.0 that matches nodes in a node-set held in a global variable. The variable holds the matching nodes, not their names.

Also, select="p|a" selects nodes in the context of the document, which is not what you want. Use `select="'p|a'"` to set the variable to a string. It helps to use an `as` attribute, eg. `as="node()*"` or `as="xs:string"` to avoid confusion as to what the variable actually is supposed to hold.

To match on the names, use `match="*[local-name()=tokenize($container, '\|')]"`

Alternatively you could define a static parameter and a shadow attribute:

```
<xsl:param name="container" select="'p|a'" static="yes"/>

<xsl:template _match="{$container}">...</xsl:template>
```

Or if you prefer, you could initialize the variable to the set of matching nodes like this:

```
<xsl:param name="matching-nodes" select="//p | //a"/>
```

and then match using

```
<xsl:template match="$matching-nodes"/>
```

But note this only works if you're matching nodes in the primary source document.

Comment: According to http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_tokenize.html, the '|' regex needs to be escaped with a backslash. With that change this worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I didn't see Dr. Kay answer, so take this just as an expansion on his.

---

The result is the expected one. From https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#patterns

> - `$xyz` matches any node that is present in the value of the variable `$xyz`.

From https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#dt-global-variable

> For a global variable or the default value of a stylesheet parameter,
>   the expression or sequence constructor specifying the variable value
>   is evaluated with a singleton focus as follows:
>
> - If the declaration appears within the top-level package (including    within an `xsl:override` element in the top-level package), then the
>     focus is based on the global context item if supplied, or absent
>     otherwise.
> - If the declaration appears within a library package, then the focus    is absent.

The current specification does a good job warning about posible difference between the global context item (context for your global variable declaration) and the initial match selection (the firts items to be processed), but that lets you in the need to look at in your XSLT processor own documentation what are the default settings...

I will assume the situation expressed as a note in the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#dt-global-context-item):

> **Note:**
>
> In previous releases of this specification, a single node was
>   typically supplied to represent the source document for the
>   transformation. This node was used as the target node for the implicit
>   call on `xsl:apply-templates` used to start the transformation process
>   (now called the initial match selection), and the root node of the
>   containing tree was used as the context item for evaluation of global
>   variables (now called the global context item).*[...]*

That combined with [Built-in Template Rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#built-in-rule) results in the following workflow:

1. The variable `$container` is set in the context of the document node
   or root: the expression selects the `p` document element.
2. The document node or root is matched by built-in rule. Apply
   templates to children.
3. The document element `p` is matched by your template. Output your
   content template and apply templates to children.
4. Each five children of `p` document element are matched by built-in
   rule: two whitespace only text nodes are output, three elements are
   bypassed.
5. The three text nodes `paragraph1`, `paragraph2` and `link here` are
   output.